# Condition for $N! > A^N$

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

I am given $A$ , I need to find minimum value of $N$ such that the condition $N! > A^N$ holds.

EXAMPLE : If $A=2$ then minimum $N=4$ and similarly if $A=3$ then minimum $N=7$.
How to solve this problem?

Comment: You mean the minimum natural number, don't you?

Comment: @mathlove yeah, minimum natural number to satisy this condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve

$$({\frac{n}{e})}^n\sqrt{2\pi n}-A^n = 0$$

with numerical methods, for example the bisection method.

The approximation of n! is good enough even to solve the A=2-case.
The uprounded result is the desired number.

Since

$$n^n > n!$$

for all $n>1$, the desired number must be >A .

So, by induction you can easily prove that the inequality also holds for 
all larger numbers.

Since

$$(3A)! > A^{3A}$$

for any $A\ge1$ (because of $n!>(\frac{n}{3})^n$ , which follows easily
from stirlings formula), 3A is an upper bound for all A.

Comment: How to use stirling approximation here?Please explain

Comment: Are you sure that Stirling's approximation is reliable when A is large? It gives the wrong integer part when n is large (and n has to be large in the case of large A).

Comment: It is not necessary to compute n! to the last digit, but only to solve the equation. I tried with PARI and for 1<A<500, everything went perfectly right. The approximation is good enough to solve even the A=2 - case. If A does become too large, you can take the logarithms to get smaller numbers and to solve the equation easier.

Comment: @Peter Can you say something about the maximum value i need to search for to find the N. i mean in terms of A(just an upper bound) like 2A or 3A or 4A like that

Comment: @Peter yeah i too analysed it to be 5A. Can u be more precise if u can?Means can it be lesser as A can be very large.(of range 1000000)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is equivalent to determining for which $N$ it holds that $\sqrt[N]{N!} >A$.

From Stirling approximation it follows that $N! = (N/e)^N \sqrt{  c_N N}$ with $1 < c_N < 2\pi$, and hence $\sqrt[N]{N!} = \frac{N}{e} \sqrt[2N]{ c_N N}$. This means that $ \frac{N}{e} < \sqrt[N]{N!} <  \frac{N}{e} C_k$ for $N \geq k$, where $C_k = \max_{N \geq k}\sqrt[2N]{ c_N N} \leq \sqrt[2k]{ c_k k} $ are constants with $C_k \to 1$ as $k \to \infty$.

Thus, for the optimal value of $N$ you have $\frac{Ae}{C_k} < N < Ae$, provided that you know a priori that $N > k$. In other words, you need to take $N \simeq Ae$, and this approximation gets better as $A$ grows. This gives the answer up to a small multiplicative factor. With a more refined version of Stirling, you might try to get a more precise answer.

Algorithmically speaking, $Ae$ is a good place to start the search for the right $N$. The value  $\sqrt[N]{N!}$ is increasing with respect to $N$, so some form of binary search should work.